# Power BI Embedded - App Owns Data - KeyVault example

Tags: sample, azure-keyvault, powerbi-embedded

Good Morning,

I'm looking to implement this but the provided examples have always held the secret in the code.  The advice is to move it to Azure KeyVault, which would be fine if there was documentation on how to achieve this with the latest incarnation of both the .NET Core sample and the KeyVault module.

[https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/.NET Core/Embed for your customers](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/.NET%20Core/Embed%20for%20your%20customers)

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets

Although I somehow managed to achieve this with an earlier .NET framework version and the previous KeyVault module, I've not managed to do the same with this primarily due to a lack of documentation or examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use AzureCLI to setup the key vault

1. Create Resource Group `az group create --name "myResourceGroup" -l "EastUS"`
2. Set up Key Vault `az keyvault create --name "<your-keyvault-name>" -g "myResourceGroup"`
3. Add a secret `az keyvault secret set --vault-name "<your-unique-keyvault-name>" --name "mySecret" --value "Success!"`

In your .NET project

1. Add package `Azure.Identity`
2. Add Package `Azure.KeyVault.Secrets`
3. Add the following references in Startup.cs

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Azure.Core;
```

4. In Startup.cs add use the following code example to retreive a keyvalue secret

```
var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://samplevault.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential()); 
var secretTask = secretClient.GetSecretAsync("mySecret"); 
Console.WriteLine(await secretTask);
```

Referenced Documentation from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app